# How to get pretty output from rest_framework serializer

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using the django rest_gramework serializer, to dump json of my objects:

```
response = InstallSerializer(Install.objects.all(), many=True).data
return StreamingHttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

where

```
class InstallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    modules = ModuleSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Install
        fields = ('id', 'install_name', 'modules')
```

etc.

However, this output is not "readable" ... it comes all on one line.

```
{'id': 1, 'install_name': u'Combat Mission Battle For Normandy', 'modules': [{'id': 1, 'name': u'Combat Mission Battle For Normandy', 'versions': [{'id': 1, 'name': u'1.00-Mac', 'brzs': [1, 2, 3]}]}]}
```

Is there a way to askk the serializer to format the output better?

(For visual inspection for debug)

**Note:** I just learned that my approach for outputting the serialized form shown above does not even produce valid json, though it looks similar.   You have to do the json.dump step shown in the accepted answer below to get valid json, and as a bonus it is pretty as well.

Comment: You can always use the Browsable API http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api#urls for debugging. It prints the JSON in a readable format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are using rest_framework you shouldn't use `json.dumps` yourself, since the renderers do this work for you. The data you see is the python dictionary, which is the output of the serializer. It does not get rendered by DRF, because you are are returning a Django `StreamingHttpResponse`. This data needs to be rendered to get your JSON. 
Is there a reason for you bypassing the rest_framework rendering?

Otherwise, this is your Handler:

```
return Response(InstallSerializer(Install.objects.all(), many=True).data)
```

Where `Response` is `rest_framework.response.Response`.

If your client needs pretty json: The rest_framework `JSONRenderer` supports the `indent` argument for the `Accept` header (see [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers#jsonrenderer)).

So when your client sends:

```
Accept: application/json; indent=4
```

Your JSON will be indented.

Comment: Thanks, I need to absorb this!

Comment: Hmm - I've tried to implement this, but I get "accepted_renderer not set on Response".   I put REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer')} to no avail....

Comment: I found I needed to add @api_view(['GET', 'POST']) annotation to my handler.

Answer (score 13):

I did this with:

```
class PrettyJsonRenderer(JSONRenderer):    
    def get_indent(self, accepted_media_type, renderer_context):
        return 2
```

And then specify `PrettyJsonRenderer` in your site's `settings.py` file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'myapp.util.PrettyJsonRenderer',
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just added the `get_indent()` method to our existing custom JSON Renderer class and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, the idea of overriding the renderer is the key

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Denis Cornehl's answer, you can also force pretty-printed output without the client specifying such in its `Accept:` header. Instead, you specify it in the `renderer_context` parameter when you call `render()` like this:

```
content = JSONRenderer().render(data, renderer_context={'indent':4})
```

By tweaking the example from the [Django Rest Framework's tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization#using-modelserializers), you can pretty-print all JSON serialized objects:

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data, renderer_context={'indent':4})
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

use below line

```
import json
return StreamingHttpResponse(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')),   mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Nice one!   This also appears to solve the problem that the raw output from the serializer (`response`) was not actually valid json, which I was just discovering as I explored the options faouto pointed me at.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this serves your use case best, but I found out i get a more readble result when i call pprint on the dict() of a ReturnDict object:

```
ipdb> type(self.response.body)
<class 'rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnDict'>
ipdb> dict(self.response.body)
{'status': 'Open', ..., 'voucher_discounts': []}  # all on one line
ipdb> pprint(dict(self.response.body))
{'currency': u'EUR',
 'id': 1,
 'lines': [OrderedDict([('url', u'http://testserver/api/baskets/1/lines/1/'), ...]), ...],
 ...
 'voucher_discounts': []}
```

Still  it won't format into the list of dicts in 'lines' though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your view by adding `headers={'indent': '    '}` in response. Try this:

```
class JSONListView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = YourSerializer

    def get_renderers(self):
        return [JSONRenderer()]

    def get_renderer_context(self):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
        response = Response(data=serializer.data, headers={'indent': '    '})
        return response
```